# NestJS Create Reusable/Publishable Library

Tags: nestjs

I want to create a Nest.js Package, so I can reuse a controller in multiple Nest.js projects.

I have checked out [library](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/libraries) but that doesn't seem to be what I was looking for because it seems to that it is only possible to import the library within the repo.

What the best way to have a library that could be published via npm so I can install and import it in other Nest Projects?

Answer (score 17):

This is how I ended up doing it

1. Create Folder and initialize Node Package

```
    mkdir PACKAGE_NAME
    cd PACKAGE_NAME
    npm init    // Follow the steps to initialize npm package
```

2. install the following dependencies and dev dependencies

```
    npm install @nest/common rxjs reflect-metadata
    npm install -d @types/node rimraf typescript
```

3. Afterwards go to your `package.json` and change/add `main`, `types`, `scripts` to the following

```
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
        "prepublish": "npm run build"
    },
```

4. Run `npm install`
5. Create `tsconfig.json` file in your folder
6. Add following code to `tsconfig.json`

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es2017", "es7", "es6"],
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "exclude": [
            "node_modules",
            "dist"
        ]
    }
```

7. Create `src` folder. Add your Nest code in this folder.
8. Add a `index.ts` file in your `src` folder. In this file you export your Nest Code, that you want to use outside of this package. For Example:

```
    import { CpuUtilizationModule } from "./cpu-utilization-observer.module";
    import { CpuUtilizationService } from "./cpu-utilization.service";

    export { CpuUtilizationModule, CpuUtilizationService }
```

This exports a Module and a Service, wich you can import/provide in your Nest Project

9. Run `npm run build`. This will compile your code to into the `dist` folder.

Now you can install this package (locally) with `npm i PATH_TO_PACKAGE`.

Comment: @nest/common library doesn't exists and doesn't work at point 4 with @nestjs/common

Comment: I believe we would want to inject both @nestjs/core @nestjs/common.  I see the common package in the new nestjs version. Could you please recheck

Comment: @Nibia it's @nestjs/common

Answer (score 6):

one of the best ways to do it is by creating a dynamic module. 
this topic will help you with [click here](https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370). 
for publish it via npm, this article will be your guide to do it with a clear way [Publishing NestJS Packages with npm](https://dev.to/nestjs/publishing-nestjs-packages-with-npm-21fm)

Answer (score 3):

Answering this as I needed to do the same before I find your approach.

I also landed on the [documentation page](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/libraries) where they mentioned that the command:

```
nest g library my-library
```

Creates libraries for monorepos:

> A Nest library is a Nest project that differs from an application in
> that it cannot run on its own. A library must be imported into a
> containing application in order for its code to execute. The built-in
> support for libraries described in this section is only available for
> monorepos (standard mode projects can achieve similar functionality
> using npm packages).

And since we wanted a standalone library, [this comment](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/213#issuecomment-645950318) from NestJS's creator might be what we needed:

> for standalone libraries (publishable to NPM), you can simply create a new Nest project and remove the `main.ts` file :)

Which seems to be another easy alternative to take

Comment: I wish the official docs were more clear about this option. You still have to do other things like the import/export index.ts,  the package.json changes, peerDependencies etc...